# CSS Hover style remains after mouse is no longer hovering

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, safari, hover

The following happens in Safari Version 7.0.1 and IE8.

Steps to reproduce the problem:
http://goo.gl/lP3Ky1

Problem:
The row's hover state remains after dismissing the popup menu, and it will not go away no matter where the mouse is, until you hover over it again.

What is the expected behavior?
The row's hover state should go away after dismissing the popup menu.

Does anybody know a fix for Safari Version 7.0.1 and IE8? I would be okay with some manual way to "untrigger" the css hover state.

Comment: The bug also exists in Safari 6.1, but as far as I can see, the dev tools show the hover state just fine.

Comment: @Marcel it isn't a browser bug

Comment: @AmitJoki it is, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170570

Comment: I faced the similar issue on safari after trying lots of workaround I finally used "mouseover" and "mouseout" events and removed :hover pseudo selector from my css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting issue to solve.  And while the solution is a bit hacky, it works.  After setting the HTML to "boo" we clone the entire row, insert it, and remove the old one:

```
$(function() {
  $("table").on("click", "td", function() {
    $("#menu")
        .clone()
        .one("click", function() {
              var $td = $(this).closest("td"),
                  $tr = $td.parent();

              $td.html("boo");
              $tr.clone(/* true */).insertAfter($tr);
              $tr.remove();
              return false;
        })
        .appendTo(this)
        .show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/3BUaT/26/

Comment: Thereby the "wrong approach" doesn't become more correct! ;-)

Comment: When a wrong approach is your only approach, it becomes less wrong ;)  The browsers are not registering the mouseout event when the menu disappears.  I even tried to animate the menu to the left in order to force a mouse-boundary crossing... to no avail.

Comment: "When a wrong approach is your only approach ..." then you have a fault in your design! ;-) And I think I showed in my answer, that it is not "the only approach". So no argument for "doing things the wrong way"!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround - http://jsfiddle.net/3BUaT/11/ . After going through many stackoverflow posts, understood that it is not possible to remove css pseudo class from javascript. So definitely a work around was necessary.

I'm using

```
tr.hovered td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

instead of regular CSS hover state.

The problem is that when you click on an li in menu, it's not exactly triggering mouseout event from CSS in safari. Technically speaking, you did not actually took your mouse out of the element. It's just that the element was removed. This seems like a bug in safari.

Comment: this is a solid javascript solution. but i would not want to force functioning browsers into accomplishing the hover styles with javascript but stick to css´s :hover.

Comment: @Marcel: This sounds a bit funny, as the whole menu thing depends on Javascript! Whether it's a bug or not in these brwosers it is at least "bad practice" (adding absolute positioned elements by script to a table-cell which are also positioned "outside" the cell and then to remove them again). I also do not understand why the hover pseudo-class belongs to the table-row (instead of the cell)!? And additionally have a look at what is happening if  the user clicks on several cells (on each click a menu is added, but none of them "disappears" so they all overlap). Your whole approach is not ideal.

Comment: @Marcel: So if you want the hover effect by CSS even when JS is disabled, use a `no-js` class in your HTML element like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) does it. And use the proposed JS solution if JS is available!

Answer (score 2):

Its not browser's fault. Its yours. You are appending the menu list to the row. So the menu list is a child of the row. So if you hover over child, the parent will also be in hover state.

I've updated your jsfiddle:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BUaT/27/);

```
$(function() {
  $("td").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu")
        .clone()
        .one("click", function() {
          // this is key to reproduce it.
          $(this).closest("td").html("boo");
          return false;
        })
        .appendTo($(this).parent().parent().last())
        .show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the div #menu to the td with your function. Now the CSS is going to apply the hover state to the td when you mouseover either the td or the appended menu. Hovering over the menu applies the tr:hover td css, because the menu is now part of the td.

Comment: this might be true. but I am looking for a fix or workaround to make extactly this work in safari and IE8. it works in all other browsers. i would be okay with some manual way to "untrigger" the css hover state...

Answer (score 1):

OK, so here is my proposed solution which takes the points from my comments (on Tejas Jayasheel's answer) into account: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJjt5/2/)

The differences are:

- #menu is not cloned and not added to the table cell, but instead just repositioned (so the element is also only displayed once)
- CSS hover only applied if the 'no-js' class is present in the HTML element (need to be added in your original file)
- otherwise hover effect is achieved by applying the class "clicked" to the cell
- additionally when menu is already visible the hover effect is "disabled" by toggling another class on all TD's
- clicking outside the menu on the already "clicked" cell will close/hide the menu without any further action

  `.no-js td:hover,

  td.hover-enabled:hover,

  td.clicked {
        background-color: lightblue;
  }`

> What is the expected behavior? The row's hover state should go away after dismissing the popup menu.

Maybe ...! But keep in mind that you are heavily "confusing" the browser by removing the hovered element from DOM. I guess that Safari and IE 8 simply "do not recognize" that former hovered part isn't hovered anymore. This may or may not be a "bug". But at least it is "bad practice/ writing style" and should simply be avoided!

> Does anybody know a fix for Safari Version 7.0.1 and IE8? I would be okay with some manual way to "untrigger" the css hover state.

The "fix" is shown in my example. It is a common recommendation to add, remove or toggle classes when it comes to scripting and hover. By doing so you avoid the "problem" at all. Because even in future versions of any browser the behaviour in such cases is "unpredictable" at best.